# Роутинг на FastCGI

Tags: php, роутер

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой роутинга на хостинге с FastCGI.

На локале работает все отлично, но после загрузки на сервер с FastCGI мне выдало ошибку

> No input file specified

Во всех модулях, кроме главной страницы. Погуглив, нашел статью, в которой описывается как исправить мою проблему. Статья: [Как два пальца ... No input file specified](http://cogear.ru/no-input-file-specified-569.html).

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Все модули заработали, но теперь не работают GET запросы выше корня сайта. Например, `http://сайт/main/category/Razrabotka/?page=2` Именно `$_GET['page']` не хочет работать.

Дамп выводит только

```
Array
(
    [main/category/Razrabotka/] => 
)
```

Буду благодарен за правильный ответ :)

---

**Решение найдено**: вместо ? в GET нужно делать &.  Потому что роутинг проходит так: `site/?_router=main/blabla/ololol/&page={num}`

А в .htaccess `/index.php?$1 [L]`.

Comment: Shrek, я образно сказал "обрезаются". 
Написал в решении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй поставить еще

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /

<?php phpinfo(); ?> // с хостинга в студию.
```

т.к. может на хостинге

```
register_globals = On
safe_mode = On
```

А они должны быть отключены

Comment: Не помогло

Comment: PHPinfo http://wapjobs.ru/?info

Comment: Нет safe_mode и register_globals отключены

Comment: Хм.. через http://wapjobs.ru/main/category/Razrabotka/&page=4 работает все.

Но после /? обрезается весь GET

Comment: Где обрезается то???
Где ты эти данные получить не можешь если скрипты отрабатывают нормально?